# Can I put a 4500 mAh 18650 li-ion battery on a 2600 mAh powerbank?

Tags: batteries, charger, lithium-ion

I recently bought a mobile phone powerbank without realising that the battery wasn't included on the kit. So now I need to buy a 18650 li-ion battery and I found one that has 4500 mAh. Can I put the 4500 mAh 18650 li-ion battery on a 2600 powerbank without damaging the device?

Comment: Is it just one cell before and after or is it a pack of cells?

Comment: It's just a cell

Comment: There is no 18650 cell in existence with a capacity of 4500 mAh. You're being lied to.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! Please add some additional context to your post so we can provide assistance: model number and link to the power bank and the same for the replacement battery.

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Power-4500mAh-Rechargeable-Lithium-Battery/dp/B00VQ4VZV2

Comment: I bought here http://www.ebay.com/itm/351760534101?_trksid=p2057872.m2749.l2649&var=620690133754&ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT

Comment: It'll work just fine, because there's no such thing as a 4500mAh 18650 li-ion cell and what you're seeing is a lie on the label. That cell is in all likelihood somewhere in the 2200-2600mAh range

Comment: Don't buy that battery. Best case scenario it is a decent quality 2.5-3 Ah Li/ion battery. Worst case scenario, it is around 1 Ah and fails or catches on fire after a few uses. Can you provide a link to the powerbank?

Comment: +1 on that other people said about capacity but safety-wise, you can increase the capacity of the battery by replacing it without problems.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, should be alright I think, at least as far as the capacity difference. It'll take longer to charge (and discharge), but the cell voltage is still 3.7V, the powerbank shouldn't notice much difference.

Comment: This may not work if the charging controller integrates current over time (so-called "coulomb counting")